# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in firebase real time database with geofire

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, geofire

I have node js server with express framework with latest version when My server try to running this code parallel this gives me error like this

```
node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8458
        if (other === this) {
        ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8458:9)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
    at ChildrenNode.equals (node_modules/geofire/dist/geofire/index.cjs.js:8466:37)
```

Here is the my code example

```
function getNearBy(
  center,
  maxRadius,
  stepRadius = 0.5,
  startRadius = 0
) {
  var tableRef = firebaseTable.ref("table1");
  var findRef = firebaseTable.ref("table2");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const queryResults = [],
        geoQuery = findRef.query({
          center,
          radius: Math.min(maxRadius, startRadius || stepRadius)
        });
      geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
        var ref = tableRef.child(key);
        ref.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const val = snapshot.val();
            queryResults.push(val)
          }
        });
      });
      geoQuery.on("ready", () => {
        if (queryResults.length > 6) {
          geoQuery.cancel(); // unsubscribe all event listeners and destroy query
          resolve(queryResults);
          return;
        }
        if (geoQuery.radius() >= maxRadius) {
          geoQuery.cancel(); // unsubscribe all event listeners and destroy query
          resolve(queryResults);
          return;
        }
        geoQuery.updateCriteria({
          radius: Math.min(maxRadius, geoQuery.radius() + stepRadius)
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  });
}
const getNearByIDs = ({ pick_up_latitude, pick_up_longitude, radius }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async function main() {
      try {
        const pick_up_geopoint = [
          parseFloat(pick_up_latitude),
          parseFloat(pick_up_longitude)
        ];
        
        let id = await getNearBy(
          pick_up_geopoint,
          radius
        );
        resolve(id);
        return;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
    }
    main();
  });
};
const notify = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async function main() {
      try {
        const totalMS = 1000;
        let removeDriver = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
          setTimeout(myFunction, i * totalMS);
          async function myFunction() {
            try {
              let ids = await getNearByIDs({
                pick_up_latitude: xx,
                pick_up_longitude: xx,
                radius: xx
              });
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("error", error);
              return;
            }
          }
        }
        return;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
    }
    main();
  });
};
```

When I try to call notify function parallel more than 2-3 times it is breaking down entire server.
Please help me with this issue
**Thank you**